# Can't measure the current in my PV cell

Tags: current, resistors, solar-cell

I have a PV cell the size of 50cmx35cm. The voltage and current it produce on short circuit is around 20.5V and 0.9A. I'm trying to measure the power that I could get from it by measuring the voltage and current it produce across a resistor, but when I try that, the measurement I get from multimeter for current is 0, while the resistor show OL(Overlimit/overload?) when I try reading it with the connection on.

I try covering 15% of the PV cell to reduce the voltage produced to around 18V and then suddenly the current is flowing again. At first I thought that maybe my resistor couldn't handle that much voltage(its 20W and 240ohm) so I change to a stronger one(30W 240ohm), but it still show the same result. I have no idea what's wrong right now, and I don't think its the connection as its a simple connection from the PV cell direct to the resistor.

I'll also include the spec of my PV cell.[image]

this one is not my picture, but its how its connected.

[image]

Comment: If you are going to use a load resistor, don't use the current range of the meter.  Simply connect the resistor across the solar panel and measure the voltage across the resistor.  Because you know the value of the resistor, simple math will tell you the current value.

Comment: that's what I did actually, directly connecting it to the solar panel(The black wire on the picture is actually already been cut). what I'm trying to do is find the optimum resistor to use to get the maximum power from the solar cell. However, the voltage always show the same value for all the resistors I use(always 20V).

Comment: Draw a circuit diagram showing how the meter, PV cell, and resistor are connected.  What resistor values are you trying?

Comment: I added a picture on how its connected. taken from the internet, but its the same as the one drawn(just not a power resistor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I would expect this.
[image]

Based on above 100% Solar input 10W 18V 0.56A

Rpm=32.4Ω  (nearest=33Ω) 10W full sun
using \$R_{mp}=\frac{V_{mp}^2}{W_{max}}\$

Then increase R for reduced Solar input for Pmax

Comment: can you explain in a bit more details, like what I should do to be able to take the current value of the resistors?

Comment: measure current by reading voltage. I=V/R   Only measure/verify  resistance  out of circuit.

Comment: that's what I did. The problem is voltage shows 20V for all different resistors I use, meaning no current flows to all the resistors. My project needs me to find suitable resistors to get the maximum power from the solar panel. The problem is all of the resistors give the same result, leaving my project hanging like this for a month now.

Comment: your lack of test results for 33 Ohms is an issue.  Put across PV and measure voltage. this V/33=I is the current.

Comment: So you're saying 33ohm is the optimum resistor value if I want to get the maximum power from this solar panel?

Comment: yes ...for the 3rd time

Comment: alright, I'll try that first and see how it goes later

Comment: late answer, but it seems that you're right.
funny thing is I did test the circuit with 0 to 100 Ohm before, but i used the cheap resistor, making them unable to show the correct value. I only used the better one for 100ohm and above, no wonder the reading shows 0 current. wow I wasted more than a month trying to figure this out.

thanks